# Is it possible to use an Action without a FormBean (Struts 1)?

Tags: java, struts-1, struts1

I'm learning struts 1, yes, the old one.

Is it possible to use an Action (Dispatch Action for example) without a FormBean?

I know that is possible to use a FowardAction, but I want to use a DispatchAction because I need to use a Controller, but I don't need a FormBean, I'll get information from the query string.

Comment: Can't definitively confirm - but I think so.  The incoming ActionForm in `execute(..., form, ...)` should just be null.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to configure my **struts-config.xml** with: `<action-mappings><action ...` without the atribute: `name="somethingForm"`... but I need to create a FormBean.

Comment: I found a solution: `DynaActionForm` but the guy who wrote the article explain that DynaAction isn't a good practice.

Comment: You mean the XML configuration without the name attribute doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, for example: `<action path="/user" type="com.keylesson.action.UserAction" parameter="dispatch" />`, I receive this error: `Form bean not specified on mapping for action`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this

```
<action-mappings>

    <action path="/myAction" name="myAction" scope="request" type="com.example.app.action.MyAction">
    </action>

</action-mappings>
```